# How to connect to Nvidia MPS server from a Docker container?

Tags: docker, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I want to overlap the use of the GPU by many docker containers. Nvidia provides an utility to do this: the Multi Process Service which is documented [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/pdf/CUDA_Multi_Process_Service_Overview.pdf). Specifically it says:

> When CUDA is first initialized in a program, the CUDA driver attempts
>   to connect to the MPS control daemon. If the connection attempt fails,
>   the program continues to run as it normally would without MPS. If
>   however, the connection attempt succeeds, the MPS control daemon
>   proceeds to ensure that an MPS server, launched with same user id as
>   that of the connecting client, is active before returning to the
>   client. The MPS client then proceeds to connect to the server. All
>   communication between the MPS client, the MPS control daemon, and the
>   MPS server is done using named pipes.

By default, the named pipes are placed in `/tmp/nvidia-mps/`, so I share that directory with the containers using a volume.

But this is not enough for the cuda driver on the container to "see" the MPS server.

Which resources should I share between the host and the container so it can connect to the MPS server?

Comment: [this](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/419) may be of interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start a container with access to mps, it must have a bind mount to `/tmp/nvidia-mps` and the same [interprocess-communication group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) as the host.

For example:

```
docker run -v /tmp/nvidia-mps:/tmp/nvidia-mps --ipc=host nvidia/cuda
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that mapping /tmp/nvidia-mps into the container is required.  As long as the IPC namespace is the same, it should work.

If you are running the MPS control daemon on the host then you would need to use the docker run flag --ipc=host, as previously mentioned, because MPS will be using /dev/shm (this is where the IPC namespace maps to) on the host.  Using the --ipc=host flag will tell docker to map the host's /dev/shm into the container, rather than creating a private /dev/shm inside the container.

E.g.

```
docker run --ipc=host nvidia/cuda
```

Note it is also possible to host MPS inside a container and share that container's IPC namespace (/dev/shm) between containers.